# Selecting Dates to sql and Sum

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Good day. I am Selecting Dates to MYSql and I select it one by one. I want to select all one week. And I used to select it individually.

Here is my code:

```html
<?php
$chart6 = $controller->runQuery("SELECT SUM(amount) FROM tbl_paid WHERE pay_date >= :today - INTERVAL 6 DAY"); 
$chart6->execute(array(":today"=>$today));
$chartData6 = $chart6->fetchColumn();

$chart5 = $controller->runQuery("SELECT SUM(amount) FROM tbl_paid WHERE pay_date >= :today - INTERVAL 5 DAY"); 
$chart5->execute(array(":today"=>$today));
$chartData5 = $chart5->fetchColumn();

$chart4 = $controller->runQuery("SELECT SUM(amount) FROM tbl_paid WHERE pay_date >= :today - INTERVAL 4 DAY"); 
$chart4->execute(array(":today"=>$today));
$chartData4 = $chart4->fetchColumn();

$chart3 = $controller->runQuery("SELECT SUM(amount) FROM tbl_paid WHERE pay_date >= :today - INTERVAL 3 DAY"); 
$chart3->execute(array(":today"=>$today));
$chartData3 = $chart3->fetchColumn();

$chart2 = $controller->runQuery("SELECT SUM(amount) FROM tbl_paid WHERE pay_date >= :today - INTERVAL 2 DAY"); 
$chart2->execute(array(":today"=>$today));
$chartData2 = $chart2->fetchColumn();

$chart1 = $controller->runQuery("SELECT SUM(amount) FROM tbl_paid WHERE pay_date >= :today - INTERVAL 1 DAY"); 
$chart1->execute(array(":today"=>$today));
$chartData1 = $chart1->fetchColumn();

$chart0 = $controller->runQuery("SELECT SUM(amount) FROM tbl_paid WHERE pay_date >= :today"); 
$chart0->execute(array(":today"=>$today));
$chartData0 = $chart0->fetchColumn();
?>
```

Is there query that can select the sum of the whole day of the week? or I should keep this code?

Comment: Please add some sample and expected data to your question.

Comment: He wants to select a week before the current date to his database. @cdaiga

Comment: yup. and sum all (amount) each selected day.

Comment: What Mysql version are you using?

Comment: Server version: 10.1.31-MariaDB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try it sql use `group`

```
SELECT Day(pay_date) pay_day,SUM(amount) amount 
FROM tbl_paid WHERE pay_date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 6 DAY 
GROUP BY Day(pay_date)
```

result:

```
| pay_day | amount |
|---------|--------|
|       1 |    246 |
|       2 |    200 |
|      28 |   1702 |
|      29 |   1462 |
|      30 |    864 |
|      31 |   1092 |
```

---

Test Data :

```
| amount |             pay_date |
|--------|----------------------|
|    100 | 2018-06-02T00:00:00Z |
|    123 | 2018-06-01T00:00:00Z |
|    546 | 2018-05-31T00:00:00Z |
|    432 | 2018-05-30T00:00:00Z |
|    731 | 2018-05-29T00:00:00Z |
|    851 | 2018-05-28T00:00:00Z |
|    100 | 2018-06-02T00:00:00Z |
|    123 | 2018-06-01T00:00:00Z |
|    546 | 2018-05-31T00:00:00Z |
|    432 | 2018-05-30T00:00:00Z |
|    731 | 2018-05-29T00:00:00Z |
|    851 | 2018-05-28T00:00:00Z |
|    436 | 2018-05-27T00:00:00Z |
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cb988b/11/0)

---

if you want more information then

you can use `weekday()` and `DAYNAME()`

```
SELECT WEEKDAY(pay_date) WEEKDAY,DAYNAME(pay_date) DAYNAME,SUM(amount) amount 
FROM tbl_paid WHERE pay_date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY 
GROUP BY WEEKDAY(pay_date),DAYNAME(pay_date)
```

---

result:

```
| WEEKDAY |   DAYNAME | amount |
|---------|-----------|--------|
|       0 |    Monday |   1702 |
|       1 |   Tuesday |   1462 |
|       2 | Wednesday |    864 |
|       3 |  Thursday |   1092 |
|       4 |    Friday |    246 |
|       5 |  Saturday |    200 |
|       6 |    Sunday |   1287 |
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6d86d4/6/0)

Comment: this is awesome. Thank you so much.

Comment: but one thing sir. how can I array this? for instance $date = array("array of selected")

Comment: I want to use this on my bar chart

Comment: and also how can I get the value of it to php? @IT WeiHan

Comment: try it use `mysql_fetch_array`, follow this video[PHP MySql Fetch multiple data - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ptoG63zBKxE) @Arvin Jason Cabrera

Comment: Thanks a lot. The only problem now is how can I put it's value to jquery :|

Comment: how can I get it as Mon instead of Monday? "short name"

Answer (score 0):

If you must pass the date then do:

```
SELECT DATE(pay_date) `DATE`, SUM(amount) daily_amount
FROM tbl_paid 
WHERE DATE(pay_date) BETWEEN DATE(:today) - INTERVAL 1 WEEK AND DATE(:today)
GROUP BY DATE(pay_date);
```

Else use the current date of the database.

```
SELECT DATE(pay_date) `DATE`, SUM(amount) daily_amount
FROM tbl_paid 
WHERE DATE(pay_date)>=CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 WEEK
GROUP BY DATE(pay_date);
```

You don't need to run the query seven times. Remember; don't repeat yourself (DRY).